# Nesting each in handlerbar

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am having an issue with this handlebar-template:

```
  <div id="shifts" style="visibility:hidden">
     {{#sites}}
        <div>{{name}}</div>
        {{#groups}}
           <div>{{name}}</div>
           <table>
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    {{#users}}
                       <th class='username' data-userID='{{id}}'>{{name}}</th>
                    {{/users}}
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              {{#shifts}}
                 <tr>
                    <td>{{time}}</td>
                    {{#individuals}}
                       <td class='vuorot_tyhja' id='{{id}}'>{{name}}</td>
                    {{/individuals}}
                 </tr>
              {{/shifts}}
              </tbody>
           </table>
        {{/groups}}
     {{/sites}}
  </div>
```

During testing it seems that the table actually causes the problem. If I add table, tr ,td, th tags (or others) inside the handlebars, it won't generate the output for those. So basically in this case only the #sites and #groups are shown. If I change the layout so that even sites and groups are within the table, then even those don't show up.

So the data is shown without problems if I remove the styling or ie. use div.

The test-data (if needed) is as follows:

```
var data = {
    "sites": [{
       "name": "Site",
       "groups": [{
              "name": "Ryhmä 1",
              "users": [{
                 "name": "Name1",
                 "id": 1
              },{
                 "name": "Name2",
                 "id": 2
              },{
                 "name": "Name3",
                 "id": 3
              },{
                 "name": "Name4",
                 "id": 4
              },{
                 "name": "Name5",
                 "id": 5
              }],
              "vuorot": [{
                 "time": "Ke 01.01.14",
                 "individuals": [{
                       "id": 1,
                       "name": "aamu"
                    },{
                       "id": 2,
                       "name": "aamu"
                    },{
                       "id": 3,
                       "name": "aamu"
                    },{
                       "id": 4,
                       "name": "aamu"
                    },{
                       "id": 5,
                       "name": "aamu"
                    },{
                       "id": 6,
                       "shift": "aamu"
                    },{
                       "id": 13,
                       "name": "aamu"
                    }]
              }]
           }]
        }]
    };
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found the answer from earlier posts: [Handlebars does not fill table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613352/handlebars-does-not-fill-table)

So case mostly solved. The problem fits totally the description, so with that I can debug it.